# Is it true that $A^{T}P+PA>0$ for an unstable matrix $A$ and a positive definite $P$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite

For a positive definite matrix $P$ and a matrix $A$ with all positive eigenvalues, how to guarantee that the matrix $Q=A^{T}P+PA$ is positive definite?

I know if $A$ is a stable matrix (i.e. all the eigenvalues of $A$ are in open left half plane) then $Q_{1}=A^{T}P+PA$ is negative definite but I was wondering if the analogous conclusion can be made about the definiteness of $Q$ when $A$ is an unstable matrix.

Comment: When $A$ is stable it is not true that "for all $P$, $Q<0$". Rather the theorem states "there exists a unique $P>0$ for any $Q<0$". This doesn't imply that "$Q>0$ for all $P>0$ if $A$ is unstable".

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. Consider the counterexample
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
     2   &  2\\
     1   &  2\\
\end{array}\right),\quad
P=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
     2   &  1\\
     1   &  1\\
\end{array}\right).
$$
The matrix
$$
Q=\left(\begin{array}{rr}
     10   &  9\\
     9   &  8\\
\end{array}\right)
$$
is not positive definite.

Just for clarification: if $A$ is a stable matrix, then for any negative definite $Q$ there exists such positive definite $P$ that $A^TP+PA=Q$.

Comment: Thank you for the example and the clarification.